# Skewness and kurtosis using quantiles and mean/variance

Tags: distributions, quantiles, skewness, kurtosis

I would like to ask if there is a way to get skewness and kurtosis measures if we only know the distribution's mean, variance, and certain quantiles.

Basically, the problem that I am facing is I have a universe of stocks and their returns' mean, variance, and quantiles (I can get any quantile 5th, 95th, 1st, 99th, etc.). What I cannot get is the full distribution of returns of these stocks. I would like to analyze these stocks' skewness and kurtosis based on their market capitalization.

I would appreciate any help on this. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

Edit per @whuber comments:

> Please include that information in your question. Is there a constant
>   cost of obtaining any percentile or does the cost vary with the
>   percentile? How is "getting the full distribution" related to the 1000
>   observations: are those observations the full distribution or are they
>   just a sample? If the latter, what kind of sample? Since you can
>   obtain the mean and variance, what prevents you from computing other
>   moments at the same time?

Each stock distribution consists of 1000 observations and getting the full distribution for each stock to calculate the moments would slow the process down quite a bit. There is a constant cost for obtaining any percentile for the entire universe of stocks. However, if the universe is increased and/or multiple percentiles are required, then the cost will increase. 1000 observations for each stock represent the full sample. The mean, variance, and quantiles come out of a certain system, which does not support other moments like skewness and kurtosis.

Comment: When you can obtain any quantile, you have the full distribution.  Could you indicate, then, what the obstacle to computing the moments might be?

Comment: Each stock distribution consists of 1000 observations and getting the full distribution for each stock would slow the process down quite a bit.

Comment: Please include that information in your question.  Is there a constant cost of obtaining any percentile or does the cost vary with the percentile?  How is "getting the full distribution" related to the 1000 observations: are those observations the full distribution or are they just a sample?  If the latter, what kind of sample? Since you can obtain the mean and variance, what prevents you from computing other moments at the same time?

Comment: thanks! Added more clarifications to the OP.